# Stackoverflow exception when calling dll which uses a static lib

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dllimport, dllexport

I writing a C# application that makes use of a C++ static Lib. I have wrapped the Lib in a .dll but have run into a problem. When I call the .dll function I get a `System.Stackoverflow` exception.

I have to use the .lib as its already in use elsewhere, I need solutions that will enable me to communicate with the lib from my C# program.

C#

```
CreateRegistryLocation(mPath);

[DllImport("Wrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int CreateRegistryLocation(string key);
```

C++ .dll

```
extern "C" 
{
   __declspec(dllexport) int CreateRegistryLocation(const char* key)
   {
      return RegistryNamespace::CreateRegistryLocation(key);
   }
}
```

C++ .lib

```
extern "C"
{
   int CreateRegistryLocation(const char* key);
}
```

If I remove the calls to the lib from the dll then the communication between the dll and the application seems to work as I expect.I have removed the body in the .lib and made it just return 0 so I don't believe the body of the lib function is relevant to the problem. I am not assigning the returned value to anything in C#, so there is no recursive problem I can see. At the moment the code should just be calling exe -> Dll -> Lib and the value 0 should return back up the chain.

Any insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your lib's CreateRegistryLocation function, does it get there? If yes, check if your parameter got marshalled correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__declspec(dllexport) int CreateRegistryLocation(const char* key)
{
    return RegistryNamespace::CreateRegistryLocation(key);
}
```

The likely explanation is that this function is in the `RegistryNamespace` namespace and so `RegistryNamespace::CreateRegistryLocation` is simply a non-terminating recursive call. Given the code in the question, that is the most plausible explanation.

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't realise the .dll was inside the namespace, and was wasting my time trying to come up with far more exotic explanations.